# Cant Texture paint on my mesh

Tags: texture-painting

so I am not able to texture paint my mesh
the texture is attached to mesh in shading nodes
I have deleted and added the brush again but its not painting
[image]

Comment: Can you give more details? It would also be helpful if you could share the file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could try the normal common issues: 1. Check the Normals are facing outward 2. Check that the mesh has UV for painting 3. Make sure the Image Texture used as a target is not also loaded as a Brush Texture in Circular Reference resulting in a similar color to the painting.